Do many AmE speakers pronounce "cavalry" as "calvary" and why?
Does this also occur in BrE and other Englishes?
How did this come about? Is this just a simple mistake confusing cavalry with calvary?

Huh. I'd never heard this pronunciation but MW lists it as a "nonstandard" one.

Bald-faced speculation: They may be (likely unconsciously) connecting from cavalry through horses and then cows and their young to calvary. But it’s probably more likely some kind of phonetic simplification going on. I sure can’t imagine native speakers of Spanish or French ever doing that though, given their caballo and cheval, respectively. Germans, on the other hand, have Kalb, so who knows where they’d end up.

This may be a case of metathesis, similar to the one with ask vs ax pronunciation of the word "ask".

Mt. Calvary is a fairly important landmark in Christian doctrine, or so I've heard. Several churches and businesses near me have Calvary in the name. So, calvary as a word is fairly common, at least as common as cavalry, so when cavalry undergoes metathesis, it gets reinforced by the fact that calvary is a word as well

Merriam Webster suggests that the mispronunciation of “cavalry” as “calvary” is due to a possible confusion between the two terms, to the extent that they decided to include  (\ˈkal-və-rē) as a non standard pronunciation.

These two words are often confused, enough so that we include the pronunciation for calvary (\ˈkal-və-rē) as a variant pronunciation for cavalry. Why would we do such a thing? Because a large number of people pronounce cavalry as calvary, even if they have no trouble distinguishing between the two words in writing. Our pronunciation for this variant notes that it is nonstandard, which means that many people regard the pronunciation as unacceptable, so you may want to avoid using it.

and in order to avoid confusing the two terms they add that:

If you have trouble distinguishing between these two words, it may help to remember that the word dealing with horsemen has val in the middle of it. If you associate this word with the long-running comic strip Prince Valiant (who occasionally appears on horseback), you will make the correct choice.


I don't claim to have done any research on this ... and I'm not sure how you would research the reason for a mistake. But I'd guess it's just because the two words are spelled very similarly, and "calvary" is a little difficult to pronounce for English speakers.

If it was due to 'calvary' being hard to pronounce, then surely it would be getting pronounced differently rather than 'cavalry' being pronounced differently.
